# Error message when launch the acumatica instance

Tags: acumatica

I have a problem when launch the instance of acumatica 2017 r2 version in my local pc. I already create customization project for this instance and need to unpublish this customization project.

But when I try to do that action, I got this error message when I launch the instance. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Please anyone if know how to solve this issue, will be apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This error can happen if your bin/ directory contains a DLL file that targets the wrong .NET framework version. Try to remove any non-Acumatica files from that folder.

Comment: could you please tell me which another file should be deleted besides the .dll of customize project ? because I have already delete the .dll of customize project but I still got the same error.

Comment: And also, I already update the .Net Framework of my Customize Project using version 4.7.1 in my visual studio and then rebuild it. But the same error still exist in my instance.

Comment: 4.5.2 is what your library should target. Recreate a brand new site in a different folder.

Comment: does framework 4.5.2 can be used as library of customize project for Acumatica 2017 R2 version ?. As I know Version 2017 R2 is using .net version 4.7, and if we create customize project as .dll file, we also have to used .net with the same version of acumatica. Is that correct ?

Comment: It does require framework 4.7 but if you check all the .dll under dotPeek or ILDASM you'll see it targets 4.5.2. I'm not saying it won't work, but I had issues trying to include a library targeting anything newer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx. In the Remark section, it explains potential source of this errors.

I have seen this error in other software in the past when trying to build a 32 bit application referencing 64 bits dlls.

Comment: I already change build of application into "Any" in properties of the project, but it didn't solve the issue.